# Sanitization and phpmailer security

Tags: php, beginner, security

I'm trying to set up a contact form using phpmailer. Are there any security holes in my code? I want to be sure as I feel there might be some kinda exploit I may not be aware of.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
        $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['brand'] != "") {
        $_POST['brand'] = filter_var($_POST['brand'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['brand'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid brand.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a brand.<br/>';
    }

    if ($_POST['type'] != "") {
      $error .= "<li>You forgot to select eyeglass type!</li>";
    }

    if ($_POST['message'] != "") {
        $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['message'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
    }

    if (!$errors) {

        require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
        $mail->IsSendmail(); // telling the class to use SendMail transport
        $mail->setCharset = "UTF-8";

          $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
          $mail->AddAddress("email@address.com");
          $mail->SetFrom($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
          $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["email"], $_POST["name"]);
          $mail->Subject = 'Home page contact form';
          $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
          $mail->IsHTML(true);
          $mail->Body = str_replace( "\n", '<br />', $formcontent );
          if(is_array($_FILES)) {
          $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']); 
          }
          $mail->Send();
          header('Location: http://www.google.com');

    } else {
        echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think you should use `$email` instead of `$_POST['email']` when setting the email in PHPMailer. The FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL will remove invalid characters and save it at `$email` variable and you're ignoring that when giving `$_POST['email']` to PHPMailer.